# Does af:select one choice supports range size concept?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have select one choice component dragged on to the page as filter. I have around 20 columns and each column is having select one choice as filter. and each filter having more than 1000 records. So, as the record count is much it is taking much time to load the page so, through view Accessor I have tried to display the data on to my component.

Still it is fetching all records in case soc. Is there any way to restrict the selectonechoice component to fetch all the data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use iterator's property `rangeSize` to limit `selectOneChoice` record count in case that you using separate ViewObject for this LOV.

If you use embeded LOV for ViewObject attribute, then you need to edit corresponding accessor's property, tuning section. Retrieve row from database, only up to row number. Set required value there.

Comment: Hi Nagh, Thanks for the prompt Response . But As you told i have tried accessors properties and tuning Section like Range size and Fetch Size and all..but it didn't workout. FYI i am using programmatic viewObjects There is no connections to the  database.

Comment: Oh, then implementation of this functionality is your responsibility. I can't give you exact answer for programmatic VO, However your implementation should call getMaxFetchSize/getFetchSize and follow it response. There could be something else, investigate.